# Apache2 Ubuntu default page after reverse proxy on example.com instead of Odoo website

Tags: proxy, dns, apache2, odoo, reverse

How are you?

When I config reverse proxy for the website Odoo works for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but not for example.com and then it shows apache2ubuntu default page.

The .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example   
ServerAlias www.example.com   
ServerAdmin root@example.com   
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log   
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined   

ProxyRequests Off   
<Proxy *>   
Order deny,allow   
Allow from all    
</Proxy>    

ProxyPass / http://server ip:8069/    
ProxyPassReverse / http://server ip:8069/    

<Location />    
Order allow,deny    
Allow from all    
</Location>    

</VirtualHost>
```

What would be the misconfiguration on .conf file?

Thanks for your help,
Emilio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rose for your quick answer,

So I'd aupdated Servername with example.com on Apache2Proxy.conf file:
After that, I restarted apache with:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

and then, execute the command:

```
apache2ctl -S

VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/Apache2Proxy.conf:1)
                 alias www.example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

But my knowledge of apache don't let me know if there is something wrong on this configuration.

Best regards and thanks,
Emilio

Comment: Based on the output of 'apache2ctl -S' command, you also have the 000-default.conf configuration active with example.com as ServerName. Try disabling the default config using the command 'a2dissite 000-default' then restart Apache service.

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm that your 'ServerName' is example.com, not example only.
You can also check the active virtual hosts by using the command:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Comment: Rose, I'd answer you below because the length of the answer don't allow to paste the active virtual hosts. Thanks, Emilio